# .Net Framework 4.6.1 app Error: Google.Protobuf Could not load file or assembly

Tags: protocol-buffers, .net-framework-version

I created a proof of concept standalone .Net Framework 4.6.1 console app to test a TLS with Google Protobuf comms protocol. It worked ok until I moved comms code into a .Net Class library (DLL .Net Standard 2.0) and tried to load it from my main WPF .Net Framework 4.6.1 app. I get this exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Protobuf, Version=3.21.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7d26565bac4d604' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=SrvComms
  StackTrace:
   at SrvComms.Master..ctor() in C:\src\SrvComms\Master.cs:line 22
   at SrvCommsTest.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\src\SrvCommsTest\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 27
```

What magic or evil is at play?

Many thanks in advance for ideas and hopefully solutions that do not involve migrating to later .Nets.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the DLL also needs to be .Net Framework 4.6.1. Thank you.